# Time passing display on UI in Unity in C#

Tags: unity

How can I display the time and how many days on a UI in Unity. Time would be moving faster like a week in 7 minutes?

Should I use Time.deltaTime and how do I excellerate the time it displays?

Comment: See also this [previous question on displaying large time ranges in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/164008/39518)

Answer (score 1):

When your in-game time is very different from real time (as implied by "one week = 7 minutes"), then I would advise against using the Unity time system for this. While you *can* mess with the [`Time.timeScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html) to do things like running the physics engine in slow motion or speed it up, it is not designed to handle time acceleration factors of that scale.

I would recommend you to do your own time handling in that case. Have some global object with an `Update` method where you add to *your* game-time by multiplying *your* timescale with `Time.deltaTime`, then convert *your* game-time to a human-readable string format and assign it to the [text field](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Label.html) of a text label.

Comment: What if I use an integer variable that keeps track of seconds and every time seconds reaches 59, I update the counter by 1 day or something along those lines? Would that be easier do you think? I can start by testing it in the Update part of the code then find a better place for it so as not to check so often. Although, I expect something that needs to be check less often will eventually be in Unity if it’s not already. Sorry, I am a super newbie with Unity. I have a 3D gaming idea but I plan on adding that feature to the current 2D tutorial I am doing at the moment.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: What Philipp is proposing is that you can make something as simple as a float that's calculated like CurrentFrameTime = LastFrameTime + Time.deltaTime * SpeedFactor and run this each frame. This way you can easily decide how fast your game time runs compared to real/engine time. Then you can take that float(CurrentFrameTime), convert it to human readable format like days:hours:minutes (its easy to find how to do that on the internet) and display it on screen.

Comment: Thanks for the responses!! Hope to get to your level some day. But I’m stuck with insisting on using the system real time clock and I do not want it connected to the frame rates or the game. I just need to make the real mintuts become days on the display since this would make it easier to code. I will need to find time and explore this (explore both what you guys are saying and what I’m trying to do) the next time I get free from work and I will post the code - may take a while. I will have to do more research...Thanks again for you help!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to upscale system time to an accelerated game time, you could do it something like this:

```
public class TimeDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{
    static readonly string[] DAYS_OF_WEEK = {
             "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" 
    };

    const int TICKS_PER_SECOND = 10000000; // File time is measured in 100 nanosecond increments.
    const long TICKS_PER_GAME_DAY = 60 * TICKS_PER_SECOND;
    const long TICKS_PER_GAME_HOUR = TICKS_PER_GAME_DAY / 24;
    const long TICKS_PER_GAME_WEEK = 7 * TICKS_PER_GAME_DAY;

    public string timeDisplay;
    public long ticksWithinWeek;
    public int dayOfWeek, hour, minute;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var time = System.DateTime.Now;

        ticksWithinWeek = (time.ToFileTime() % TICKS_PER_GAME_WEEK);

        dayOfWeek = (int)((ticksWithinWeek / TICKS_PER_GAME_DAY) % 7);
        hour = (int)((ticksWithinWeek / TICKS_PER_GAME_HOUR) % 24);
        minute = Mathf.FloorToInt((ticksWithinWeek % TICKS_PER_GAME_HOUR)
                 * (60f / TICKS_PER_GAME_HOUR));

        timeDisplay = string.Format("{0}:{1} {2}", 
                       hour.ToString("00"),
                       minute.ToString("00"),
                       DAYS_OF_WEEK[dayOfWeek]);
    }
}
```