# Why the timer is not showing the hours?

Tags: unity, c#

It's showing minutes seconds milliseconds but I want to show also the hours.

At the top:

```
private int seconds; // Seconds.
private int minutes; // Minutes.
private int hours;   // Hours.
```

In Update:

```
void Update()
{
if (seconds < 1)
        {
            seconds = 59;
            minutes--;
        }
        if (minutes < 1)
        {
            minutes = 59;
            hours--;
        }
        if (hours < 1)
        {
            hours = 59;
        }
        seconds--;

        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Next: ", hours.ToString() + ":" + minutes.ToString() + ":" + seconds.ToString());
```

Update, This is what I tried:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Timer : EditorWindow
{

    private static Timer editor;
    private static int width = 300;
    private static int height = 110;
    private static int x = 0;
    private static int y = 0;
    int totalSeconds;

    [MenuItem("Window/Timer")]
    static void ShowEditor()
    {
        editor = EditorWindow.GetWindow<Timer>();
        editor.Init();
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        StartTimer(1, 1, 50);
        Debug.Log("The level will now be saved automatically");
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Next: ", TimeString());
    }

    public void StartTimer(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
    {
        totalSeconds = seconds + 60 * minutes + 60 * 60 * hours;
    }

    string TimeString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",
                      totalSeconds / (60 * 60),   // Hours
                      (totalSeconds / 60) % 60, // Minutes
                      totalSeconds % 60);     // Seconds
    }
}
```

But the timer is not moving not counting back it stay still.
I tried also to move the line:

```
StartTimer(1, 1, 50);
```

To be inside the OnGUI before the LabelField.

Comment: You claim your code shows milliseconds, however there is no mention of milliseconds in the code you provided. There must be some mix-up there.

Comment: Is this something you want to tick down in realtime? Since you were subtracting 1 "second" in every update (which generally fires 30+ times per second) regardless of how much `deltaTime` had actually passed, I assumed you were trying to make a decorative countdown effect. If you really want to measure real time in the editor and trigger a save after a particular realtime interval, why not use a literal, standard [Timer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: @DMGregory I'm using now the Timers and using Timer and it's working fine for hours minutes seconds but if I want to add also milliseconds ? How can I do it inside the elapsed event T_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) ? Inside the elapsed event I can make the hours minutes seconds but not milliseconds.

Comment: I've edited my comment to clarify that the Timer is for triggering your save once the time is up. You can use a [Stopwatch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.7.2) for tracking the countdown, or a TimeSpan as Phillipp demonstrates in an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing your own date and time handling code from scratch is a path towards agony and despair. It is usually far better to use the time handling features provided by your platform. In the case of C#, the standard library offers you a handy [`TimeSpan`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.7.2) class.

```
 TimeSpan timer = new TimeSpan(1, 1, 50);
 Debug.Log("The timer is set to " + timer.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss"));
```

The class also has a bunch of methods which allow you to modify the value in an easy and painless way. For example, if you want the Update method of a MonoBehaviour to reduce the remaining time:

```
 Update() {
    TimeSpan deltaTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Time.deltaTime);
    timer = timer.Subtract(deltaTimeSpan);
    Debug.Log("Time left: " + timer.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss"));
 }
```

Comment: You could also use `timer = timer.AddSeconds(-Time.deltaTime);` to be more succinct

Answer (score 2):

Your logic for advancing the time from one variable to the other is not correct. It skips over second 0 every minute, and minute 0 every hour.

You can simplify this greatly by storing just one variable internally, and splitting out the hours/minutes only when needed:

```
int totalSeconds;

public void StartTimer(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
    totalSeconds = seconds + 60 * minutes + 60*60 * hours;
}

string TimeString() {
    return string.format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", 
                  totalSeconds/(60*60),   // Hours
                  (totalSeconds/60) % 60, // Minutes
                  totalSeconds % 60);     // Seconds
}
```

Comment: I tried I'm using EditorWindow and OnGUI. But it's not working. Updated my question with what I did.  Either using the StartTimer in the Init or inside the OnGUI not starting the timer.

Comment: @BenziAvrumi it looks like you forgot to decrement your `totalSeconds` variable somewhere. All I showed here are the methods to initialize the time and convert it to a string. Counting it down at the frequency you want is still up to you.